# How to bind two different JavaFx properties: String and Double (with StringConverter)?

Tags: binding, properties, javafx

For this piece of code (JavaFX).

```
StringProperty sp;
DoubleProperty dp;

StringConverter<Double> converter = new DoubleStringConverter();    

Bindings.bindBidirectional(sp, dp, converter);
```

I get compilation error (in Eclipse IDE)

This is the method signature:

```
public static <T> void bindBidirectional(Property<String> stringProperty, Property<T> otherProperty, StringConverter<T> converter)
```

But if I remove parametrization (of StringConverter), then I get only warnings and code works.

```
StringConverter converter = new DoubleStringConverter();
```

I am trying to avoid to use raw type of generics so that I don't have to suppress warnings in my IDE.

> So the question is:
>   What is the right pattern to write this piece of code?

Answer (score 26):

This is probably a small "trap" in JavaFX properties. If you look closely at the signature:

```
static <T> void bindBidirectional(Property<java.lang.String> stringProperty,
    Property<T> otherProperty, StringConverter<T> converter)
```

The parameter of the converter must match the parameter of the property. But (the surprize here) `DoubleProperty` implements `Property<Number>`, thus the mismatch in `bindBidirectional`. Luckily the solution is simple: use `NumberStringConverter`:

```
StringProperty sp = ...;
DoubleProperty dp = ...;
StringConverter<Number> converter = new NumberStringConverter();
Bindings.bindBidirectional(sp, dp, converter);
```

You get the extra benefit that you can specify the conversion format.

Comment: Is there a way of doing this with unidirectional bindings?

Comment: For unidirectional bindings see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48588027/5178726)

Answer (score 0):

That is the answer of my solution:

```
    ArrayList<Pair<Slider,Label>> sliderList = new ArrayList<Pair<Slider,Label>>(
            Arrays.asList(
                    new Pair<Slider,Label>(soundSlider, soundLabel),
                    new Pair<Slider,Label>(videoSlider, videoLabel),

    sliderList.forEach(p->{
        Bindings.bindBidirectional(p.getValue().textProperty(), p.getKey().valueProperty(), new NumberStringConverter() {
            @Override
            public String toString(Number value) {
                return super.toString(Math.round((double) value));
            }
        }); 
    });
```